# Hiding a partition without formatting it

Tags: partitioning

Is it possible to hide a partition of an external HDD without formatting the partition? Is there any free program to do so?

If that's not possible, what about introducing it as a removable device by changing its removable state flag? Is it possible without formatting? (Since Windows only recognizes the first partition of a removable device, this method also *hides* the other partitions -- at least in Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to truly hide a partition is via TrueCrypt's [plausible deniability](http://www.truecrypt.org/hiddenvolume) feature. This would require formatting.

Anything else may *appear* to hide the partition, but even if Windows doesn't automatically report that it exists, it would still be accessible by software.

Comment: TrueCrypt's plausible deniability is something known, and it may not be convincing for the bad guys. I was not able to find any _truly_ undetectable/deniable encryption methods. Anyway, for this question, I'm just asking about hiding the partition to the Windows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide your Data from People or do you only want to Partition to be invisible to windows?

Because if you only want to hide the partition from windows you could either remove the drive letter or mark it has hidden
just "reverse" this method [How to make a hidden partition visible](https://superuser.com/questions/459434/how-to-make-a-hidden-partition-visible)