# How to make hidden partitions accessible in windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I've read a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/459434/how-to-make-a-hidden-partition-visible), but that solution doesn't work for me...

The current partitions on my laptop (2nd hand ASUS Vivobook) look like this:

[image: 2]

As you can tell I have a 500G HDD and 24G SSD, corresponding to Disk 0 and Disk 1. My problem is, only the OS and Data partitions are visible and accessible to me, which constitute only a fraction of my total storage space (I guess I can't use the EFI System Partition or the OEM Partition or the Recovery Partitions, but still it'd be nice if I can use all the usable "Primary Partitions")

You see when I right click on any of the invisible primary partitions, I only get "Delete Volume" or "Info" options highlighted...why can't do other things to it? Why are these partitions "hidden" in the first place?

How can I assign letters/get access to my other usable partitions? (Please explain in simple terms as I'm a simple guy and a complete tech newbie :)

Comment: How were these primary partitions created? Are they formatted using some file system other than NTFS? Have you tried deleting them, then creating new partitions in the unallocated space and formatting as NTFS?

Comment: @Karan: I don't really know how they got there; the original owner did say he used to have Linux alongside win8. The tricky part is that Disk Management doesn't recognize what file system they are...  I'll try your suggestion and see if it works!

Comment: simply deleting those partitions and reallocating worked fine for me

Comment: Good to know. Enjoy all the extra space. :)